# Bootstrap uib-carousel + angular image are not preloading

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Im using in my project angular 1.5.5 and Bootstrap v3.3.6

I want to have slider on my platform so I did use uib-carousel

This is my html code:

```
 <uib-carousel active="active"
                  interval="wellcomePage.myInterval"
                  no-wrap="wellcomePage.noWrapSlides"
                  no-pause="true">

        <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in wellcomePage.slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
            <div class="slajd" ng-style="{height:wellcomePage.pageHeigth+'px','background-image':'url({{slide.image}})'}">
                <div class="intro">
                    <div class="intro-body">
                        <p id="intro-text">{{slide.title}}</p>
                        <p id="intro-text-italic">{{slide.teaser}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </uib-slide>
    </uib-carousel>
```

and this is my angular wellcomePage.slides:

```
 wellcomePage.slides = [
    {
        id:0,
        image: "/img/wellcomepageSlides/hello1.jpg",
        title: "Yo",
        teaser: "Hi there"
    },
    {
        id:1,
        image: "/img/wellcomepageSlides/hello2.jpg",
        title: "Wellcome",
        teaser: "Be good"
    }];
```

The first problem is that when I open my page the first time an image is loading from top to down and slider is loading like this:

[image]

The second problem is when i push arrow > to slide i see something like this, and that it take while to load image from top to down:

[image]

What I have already tried:

1. Image preload using ionic.ion.imagecachefactory, I have used it like they said here https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/ionic-ion-imageCacheFactory Images are preloading but what I see on slider is not changeing.

I have also tried preloading from here http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2597-preloading-images-in-angularjs-with-promises.htm

2. I thought that it coud be my dybamic window height height:wellcomePage.pageHeigth, I have set it to static 500px in html but it didn't helped.
3. I have tried set 'background-image':'url({{slide.image}})' as 'background-image':'url(/img/wellcomepageSlides/hello1.jpg)' but it also didn't help

And I have no idea what is wrong, can any body help me, please?